# batch file list with robocopy

Tags: batch-file, robocopy

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%i  IN (loglist.txt) DO robocopy "%Src%%%i" "C:\Temp\Test" *.ininlog
```

Giving this error Error 2 Accessing Source Dir C:\Temp\Logs\2014-04-24\accserver\

Expected Operation should be copying C:\Temp\Logs\2014-04-24\accserver.ininlog

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Got it working was doing the wrong operation

```
 FOR /F "delims=|" %%i  IN (loglist.txt) DO robocopy %Src% C:\Temp\Test "%%i".ininlog
```